# How to fix U0164 error code for Chrysler 300 2006?

Tags: chrysler-300

I have Chrysler 300 2006. The check engine light is on and an error code U0164 was diagnosed. Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it? I know nothing about cars Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the car seem to drive fine?  Is there any problem with the A/C or heat?  The U indicates a communication problem, and more specifically U0164 is "Lost Communication With HVAC Control Module".

Comment: Are you sure that's the right error code.  I spent an hour looking for it and asked others to help and for the life of me, I cannot find a U0164.  Could you please verify that the code is correct?

Comment: @DucatiKiller JPhi1618 is correct U0164 is a HVAC communication code. Though typically communication codes don't set the MIL.

Comment: @ben   he usually is, I just could't find a table with the code identified in it.  btw...went at looked at some of your answers.  +many  Really good stuff.